# Can I combine elemMatch with dot notation in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

what to learn today…  I'm now with Mongodb, and reading [the reference manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-embedded-documents) and trying myself, I don't see how to match parts of an embedded document.

given this tiny plant collection:

```
{ "code" : "2016.0461.1", "lon" : -73.8603176593, "lat" : 2.06117398918, 
  "species" : "Pera arborea", 
  "dap" : { "2016-11" : 10 } }
{ "code" : "2011.0154.1", "lon" : -73.8648049304, "lat" : 2.05991990281, 
  "species" : "Terminalia amazonia",  
  "dap" : { "2013-10": 8, "2016-11" : 21 } }
{ "code" : "2006.0065.1", "lon" : -73.8672333008, "lat" : 2.05869146507,
  "species" : "Maquira coriacea",
  "dap" : { "2010-10": 80, "2013-05": 84, "2016-11" : 90 } }
```

I wish to select all trees that in November 2016 were broader than 50cm (in the above data, `dap` is the diameter of the tree at breast height, and it is measured occasionally, so I expect only the plant with code `2006.0065.1`)

`db.plants.find({"dap.2016-11" : 90})` gives the expected result, but the two queries that I could think of do not work:

- `db.plants.count({dap : {"2016-11" : {$elemMatch: {$gte:40}}}})`
- `db.plants.count({"dap.2016-11" : {$elemMatch: {$gte: 40}}})`

neither signals an error and both return 0

Comment: `dap` is an object... you cannot use `$elemMatch` with the objects

Comment: but with dot-notation, the field `dap.2016-11` would be an atomic value. not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found an answer in [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375888/how-to-combine-elemmatch-with-nin-or-not-in-a-mongodb-query): I don't need `elemMatch`, and the working query can use dot-notation:

`db.plants.find({"dap.2016-11" : {$gte: 90}})`